# XElement creation issue

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a structure like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="namespace1"
        xmlns:image="namespace2">
  <url> 
    <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.html</loc> 
    <image:image>
       <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc> 
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Any ideas on how to create the image elements using XLinq?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`XNamespace` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx).

For example:

```
XNamespace image = "namespace2";

var element = new XElement(image + "image",
    new XElement(image + "loc", someUrl)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can get exactly what your after, but this:

```
XNamespace ns1 = "namespace1";
XNamespace ns2 = "namespace2";

new XElement(ns1 + "urlset",
    new XElement(ns1 + "loc", "http://www.example.com/foo.htm"),
    new XElement(ns2 + "image",
        new XElement(ns2 + "loc", "http://example.com/image.jpg"))).Dump();
```

Should get you the equivalent.

```
<urlset xmlns="namespace1">
  <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.htm</loc>
  <image xmlns="namespace2">
    <loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</loc>
  </image>
</urlset>
```